# map 2 function combination fails: syntax error?

Tags: function, haskell, combinations

I just know in Haskell "." could be used to combine functions, so I tried:

```
Prelude> map (++" world")["hello","abc"]
["hello world","abc world"]
Prelude> map (++" world". ++"xyz")["hello","abc"]

<interactive>:3:18: parse error on input `++'
```

Why I cannot do this? I tried named function, it's OK:

```
Prelude> map (head.tail)["hello","abc"]
"eb"
```

So how to correct my case? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do this for a very very simple reason:  `++ "x"` is not an expression. In contrast, `(++ "x")` *is* an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name for the thing you are doing when you say `(++ "world")` is that you are using what is called a "right section" of a "partially applied infix operator":

https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator

What that means for `(++ "world")` is that the left hand side will be the parameter for the generated function, which will pre-fill the right hand side with "world".

So it's not just a use of parentheses for precedence... it's a special syntax.  When you omit the parentheses on the second `++`, that means you aren't invoking the syntax there.  It tries to interpret it as normal infix.

If you want to compose two functions of this type inlined like this, you have them each in parentheses:

```
Prelude> map ((++" world") . (++"xyz"))["hello","abc"]
["helloxyz world","abcxyz world"]
```

Note the effects on the result if you merely convert the ++ operators to prefix, with the non-partially-applied syntax:

```
Prelude> map ((++) " world" . (++) "xyz")["hello","abc"]
[" worldxyzhello"," worldxyzabc"]
```

There you don't have to group them, but now you are providing the first argument instead.  Your list's data winds up at the end of the output.  This would be the same as if you used the infix partial application syntax with left sections:

```
Prelude> map ((" world" ++) . ("xyz" ++))["hello","abc"]
[" worldxyzhello"," worldxyzabc"]
```

FYI: if you want the composition to be in the reverse order (world first, then xyz) you could use `>>>` from Control.Arrow

```
Prelude> import Control.Arrow
Prelude Control.Arrow> map ((++" world") >>> (++"xyz")["hello","abc"]
["hello worldxyz","abc worldxyz"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`++` is an infix operator, and the rules of how you can use it are different than that of normal functions.

You can use it sandwiched between two values, like this

```
x ++ y
```

or convert it to a normal function using parenthesis

```
(++) x y --same as above
```

There are two ways to partially apply values to an infix operator

```
(x ++) --same as \y -> x ++ y
(++ y) --same as \x -> x ++ y
```

Both of these require the outer parentheses, else Haskell would try to parse the expression as the normal infix case

```
++ x . ++ y -- will confuse the parser
```

but

```
(++ x) . (++ y)
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

Infix operators like parentheses.

```
Prelude> map ((++ " world") . (++ "xyz")) ["hello", "abc"]
```